# (Android)Trying to understand why my method will not compute/display the correct value in the textview

Tags: java, android

My method that is called (calculate BMI) inside of my activity is supposed to compute and display BMI (based on the formula inside the code), and display its value inside of a textview. The application runs correctly, however the value displayed is always zero. I am struggling to figure out if the problem lies in my formula (unlikely) or if the way that I am passing the value is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated. Code below

.Java file

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Health extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText bloodPressure;
    EditText cholesterol;
    int weight;
    int height;
    EditText heightString;
    EditText age;
    TextView bmiText;
    EditText weightString;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_health);
        weightString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightTextBox);

        heightString =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.heightTextBox);

        bmiText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiTextView);
        bloodPressure = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bloodPressureTextBox);
        cholesterol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cholesterolTextBox);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageTextBox);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    }

    public void calculateBMI(View view)
    {
        weight = Integer.parseInt(weightString.getText().toString());
        height = Integer.parseInt(heightString.getText().toString());
        int BMI = 703 * (weight/(height*height));
        bmiText.setText("Your calculated BMI is: " + Integer.toString(BMI));
        Toast.makeText(Health.this, " Info Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HealthInfo healthInfo = new HealthInfo(bloodPressure.getText().toString(),cholesterol.getText().toString(),heightString.getText().toString(),weightString.getText().toString(),age.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addHealth(healthInfo);

    }

    public void calorieClick(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CalorieTracker.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void openTips(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HealthTipsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void openPlans(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DietPlansActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_health, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

.XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="seniorproject.broncos.broncowellnessapp.Health"
    android:background="#006699">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/blood_pressure_text"
        android:id="@+id/bloodPressureTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/cholesterol_text"
        android:id="@+id/cholesterolTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bloodPressureTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/weight_text"
        android:id="@+id/weightTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cholesterolTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/height_text"
        android:id="@+id/heightTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weightTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/age_text"
        android:id="@+id/ageTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heightTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/bloodPressureTextBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bloodPressureTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/cholesterolTextBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cholesterolTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/weightTextBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weightTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/heightTextBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/heightTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/ageTextBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ageTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/diet_plans_button_text"
        android:onClick="openPlans"
        android:id="@+id/dietPlansButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ageTextBox"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calorie_tracker_button"
        android:id="@+id/calorieAccessButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dietPlansButton"
        android:onClick ="calorieClick"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tips_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/tipsButton"
        android:onClick="openTips"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calorieAccessButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calorieAccessButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/calorieAccessButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BMI_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/bmiButton"
        android:onClick="calculateBMI"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cholesterolTextBox"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dietPlansButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/dietPlansButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:background="#ff00b812" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Push Button to Compute BMI"
        android:id="@+id/bmiTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weightTextBox"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bmiButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bmiButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `weight` and `height` variables are `int`. That is your problem. Change them to `float` or `double`

Currently, you are doing integer division which is causing the result to be truncated as follows: `1 / 2` gives `0`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a division for integer which results mostly to zero.
That is why the result is always zero.

Change your weight and height variables to double like this
and just cast the result back to int.

```
double weight = 0.0;
double height = 0.0;

int BMI = (int)(703 * (weight/(height*height)));
bmiText.setText("Your calculated BMI is: " + Integer.toString(BMI));
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this on the end of the onCreate() method:

```
findViewById(R.id.bmiButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            weight = Integer.parseInt(weightString.getText().toString());
            height = Integer.parseInt(heightString.getText().toString());
            int BMI = 703 * (weight/(height*height));
            bmiText.setText("Your calculated BMI is: " + Integer.toString(BMI));
            Toast.makeText(Health.this, " Info Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            HealthInfo healthInfo = new HealthInfo(bloodPressure.getText().toString(),cholesterol.getText().toString(),heightString.getText().toString(),weightString.getText().toString(),age.getText().toString());
            dbHandler.addHealth(healthInfo);
        }
});
```

Some android version does not support onClick attribute for Button tag in XAML.